# UIWebView: Zooming and Restricting scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, calendar

My goal is to load the calendar from [here](http://www.eteamz.com/aysoregion117/calendar/) into my app. I was unable to parse it in, so instead I've tried looking into simply using a UIWebView. The problem is that the webview shows the entire page, and I just want the calendar to show up, is there any way to automatically zoom into just the calendar and restrict movement away from it (ie scrolling)?

Note: I did not include code because I don't have malfunctioning code, I need help figuring out what to code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these:

```
self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);//put the inset that you need
self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self; //implement delegate methods to restrict scrolling
```